# Mongo/Mongoose - Find by partial document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of properties that all have addresses.

```
"address" : {
    "street" : "5 Orange Drive",
    "city" : "Orlando",
    "state" : {
        "abbreviation" : "FL",
        "name" : "Florida"
    },
    "zip" : "32822",
    "geo" : {
        "lat" : 28.519,
        "lng" : -81.304
    }
},
"address" : {
    "street" : "16 Main Street",
    "city" : "Tallahassee",
    "state" : {
        "abbreviation" : "FL",
        "name" : "Florida"
    },
    "zip" : "32823",
    "geo" : {
        "lat" : 28.529,
        "lng" : -81.314
    }
},
"address" : {
    "street" : "125 Oak Drive",
    "city" : "Salem",
    "state" : {
        "abbreviation" : "MA",
        "name" : "Massachusetts"
    },
    "zip" : "02108",
    "geo" : {
        "lat" : 24.519,
        "lng" : -83.304
    }
},
"address" : {
    "street" : "96 Jones Way",
    "city" : "Springfield",
    "state" : {
        "abbreviation" : "MA",
        "name" : "Massachusetts"
    },
    "zip" : "01020",
    "geo" : {
        "lat" : 28.519,
        "lng" : -84.304
    }
},
"address" : {
    "street" : "100 Sumner Ave",
    "city" : "Springfield",
    "state" : {
        "abbreviation" : "IL",
        "name" : "Illinois"
    },
    "zip" : "32822",
    "geo" : {
        "lat" : 22.519,
        "lng" : -71.304
    }
},
"address" : {
    "street" : "40 Roger Ave",
    "city" : "Salem",
    "state" : {
        "abbreviation" : "AL",
        "name" : "Alabama"
    },
    "zip" : "32822",
    "geo" : {
        "lat" : 22.519,
        "lng" : -71.304
    }
}
```

I have an earlier query that returns an array of addresses such as:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Massachusetts - Salem',
        city: 'Salem',
        _id: 53784206cd73fbae193b62d5,
        state: [Object]
    }, {
        name: 'Illinois - Springfield',
        city: 'Springfield',
        _id: 5376fa92bde0e0ea047e9abd,
        state: [Object]
    }
]
```

I would like to use the output of the above array to search the collection of properties by address.

Such as, I would like to search for all properties where the address contains a 'city of Springfield and a state of Illinois' and 'city of Salem and a state of Massachusetts'.

I was originally trying to do this using ***$in*** with some ***$and***'s mixed in but I wasn't sure if it was possible.

Comment: What's the Object in `state: [Object]`?

Comment: {"name":"Illinois","abbreviation":"IL"}...etc. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the **[`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator on an array that contains query conditions derived from the other input array. For example, with the sample properties collection:

```
db.properties.insert([
{
    "address" : {
        "street" : "5 Orange Drive",
        "city" : "Orlando",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "FL",
            "name" : "Florida"
        },
        "zip" : "32822",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 28.519,
            "lng" : -81.304
        }
    }
},
{
    "address" : {
        "street" : "16 Main Street",
        "city" : "Tallahassee",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "FL",
            "name" : "Florida"
        },
        "zip" : "32823",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 28.529,
            "lng" : -81.314
        }
    }
},
{
    "address" : {
        "street" : "125 Oak Drive",
        "city" : "Salem",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "MA",
            "name" : "Massachusetts"
        },
        "zip" : "02108",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 24.519,
            "lng" : -83.304
        }
    }
},
{
    "address" : {
        "street" : "96 Jones Way",
        "city" : "Springfield",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "MA",
            "name" : "Massachusetts"
        },
        "zip" : "01020",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 28.519,
            "lng" : -84.304
        }
    }
},
{
    "address" : {
        "street" : "100 Sumner Ave",
        "city" : "Springfield",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "IL",
            "name" : "Illinois"
        },
        "zip" : "32822",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 22.519,
            "lng" : -71.304
        }
    }
},
{
    "address" : {
        "street" : "40 Roger Ave",
        "city" : "Salem",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "AL",
            "name" : "Alabama"
        },
        "zip" : "32822",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 22.519,
            "lng" : -71.304
        }
    }
}
])
```

The following query would give the desired result:

```
var res = [
    {
        "name": 'Massachusetts - Salem',
        "city": 'Salem',
        "_id": "53784206cd73fbae193b62d5",
        "state": [{"name": "Massachusetts", "abbreviation": "MA"}]
    }, {
        "name": 'Illinois - Springfield',
        "city": 'Springfield',
        "_id": "5376fa92bde0e0ea047e9abd",
        "state": [{"name": "Illinois", "abbreviation": "IL"}]
    }
];

var condition = res.map(function (item){
    return {
        "address.city": item.city,
        "address.state.name": item.state[0].name
    }
});

db.properties.find({"$or": condition });
```

**Sample Output**

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557848b43cab061ff5c618b7"),
    "address" : {
        "street" : "125 Oak Drive",
        "city" : "Salem",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "MA",
            "name" : "Massachusetts"
        },
        "zip" : "02108",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 24.519,
            "lng" : -83.304
        }
    }
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("557848b43cab061ff5c618b9"),
    "address" : {
        "street" : "100 Sumner Ave",
        "city" : "Springfield",
        "state" : {
            "abbreviation" : "IL",
            "name" : "Illinois"
        },
        "zip" : "32822",
        "geo" : {
            "lat" : 22.519,
            "lng" : -71.304
        }
    }
}
```